# Splitting an array at multiple points using an index point

Tags: java, arrays, random, numbers

I have come across many examples to split the given array or array list into two arrays or multiple arrays using an index point. I tried them and they are working perfectly. My question is, is it possible to split the array into multiple arrays of varying chunk size given the index point?

For example:

```
array[] = {10,1,2,3,10,4,5,10,6,7,10,8,10};
index_value = 10;
```

Then the output should be four arrays such as:

```
arr1[] = {1,2,3}
arr2[] = {4,5}
arr3[] = {6,7}
arr4[] = {8}
```

I was able to split them and display the results when the given array is static with no changes. But implementing the same for an array with random numbers and random size was hard. I need to store the split values in many sub arrays and not just printing the values.

Comment: Do you need arrays, or can you use something like `ArrayList<int>` to store your numbers?

Comment: how does having random values matter if you are using index as splitter value??

Comment: @Sam arraylist or array any is fine..but i need the split values as separate arrays..as for now i have just printed the values for a small sample array..

Comment: @Nullpointer if the split value = 10, and if the array is random then the number of 10's in the array also varies..so the number of output array is dynamic..im not sure how to implement that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this solution, the `index_value` does not have to be at the start or end of the array:

```
int[] arr = new int[]{10,10,1,10,1,2,3,10,4,5,10,6,7,10,8,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,5,4,10,10};
int index_value = 10;

/** walk through the array and create the arraylist of arraylists */
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> al = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> currAl = null;
for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == index_value) {
        if (currAl != null && currAl.size() > 0)
            al.add(currAl);
        currAl = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    } else {
        if (currAl == null)
            currAl = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        currAl.add(arr[i]);
    }
}
if (arr[arr.length-1]!= index_value && currAl.size() > 0) {
    al.add(currAl);
}

/** print out the arraylist of arraylists */
for (int i=0; i < al.size(); i++) {
    currAl = al.get(i);
    for (int j=0; j < currAl.size(); j++) {
        System.out.print(currAl.get(j) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: i will be able to use this one..its really good. Now i just need to do some processing with the elements within the lists

Answer (score 0):

You can build your arrays by using the `ArrayList` class to fill in your values

```
array[] = {10,1,2,3,10,4,5,10,6,7,10,8,10};
index_value = 10;

ArrayList<ArrayList<int>> allLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<int>>();
ArrayList<int> currentList;
for (int i = 0;i < array.length;i++)
{

    //in case your array doesn't contain the index_value at index 0
    //check for the null case
    if (array[i] == index_value || currentList == null)
    {
        currentList = new ArrayList<int>();
        allLists.add(currentList);
    }
    else
    {
        currentList.add(array[i]);
    }
}
if (allLists.size() > 0 && allLists.get(allLists.size() - 1).size() == 0)
{
    allLists.remove(allLists.size() - 1);
}
```

What you should have is an `ArrayList` that contains `ArrayList`s that contain the numbers you are interested in. If the `index_value` is repeated twice in a row, however, you will end up with empty lists (which can be removed later). This includes the final list, which I automatically remove if it is empty (since your example lists the `index_value` as being at both the start and the end.

If you would like the output to be in arrays, you can just call `.toArray()` on the [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following strategy: look for your marker boundaries, form an array from each segment as encountered, and put result in a Vector (for example).

```
package com.splitter;
import java.util.Vector;
public class Splitter {
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {10, 1,2,3,10,4,5,10,6,7,10,8,10};
    Vector <int[]> result;

    result = split(array,10);
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        int[] split = result.get(i);
        System.out.println("Array " + i);
        for (int j=0; j<split.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(split[j]);
        }
    }
}

private static Vector<int[]> split(int[] array, int value) {
    Vector<int[]> result = new Vector<int[]>();
    int loc = 0;
    int start = 0;
    boolean isInside = false;
    while (loc < array.length) {
        if (array[loc] == value) {
            if (isInside) { // make array from start to here
                // make an array from start+1 to loc-1
                System.out.println(" .." + start + " " + loc + " v=" + array[loc] );

                int[] split = new int[loc - start - 1];
                for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
                    split[i] = array[start+1+i];
                }
                result.add(split);
                isInside = true;
            } 
            start = loc;
            isInside = true;
        }
        loc++;
    }
    return result;
}

}
```

Comment: Im not sure about the vector concepts..its new to me but this solution is working perfectly. I will be able to use this as well

Comment: Vector was just a simple artifact that lets you add and find elements without knowing how many you will have.  Other data structures could be used to fit your need.  Mark accept on the answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in NetBeans, debug, and works well.

The values will be stored like in a ArrayList with more ArrayLists inside, like this:

- arrayOfIntList.get(0) = > 1,2,3

  - arrayOfIntList.get(0).get(0) -> 1
  - arrayOfIntList.get(0).get(1) -> 2
  - arrayOfIntList.get(0).get(2) -> 3
- arrayOfIntList.get(1) = > 4,5

  - arrayOfIntList.get(1).get(0) -> 4
  - arrayOfIntList.get(1).get(1) -> 5
- arrayOfIntList.get(2) = > 6,7

  - arrayOfIntList.get(2).get(0) -> 6
  - arrayOfIntList.get(2).get(1) -> 7
- arrayOfIntList.get(3) = > 8

  - arrayOfIntList.get(3).get(0) -> 8

---

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Javaprueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myarray = {10,1,2,3,10,4,5,10,6,7,10,8,10};
        int splitterInt = 10;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> tempArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayOfIntList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

        for(int i=0; i<myarray.length; i++){

            if(myarray[i] != splitterInt){
                tempArray.add(j, myarray[i]);
                j++;                          
            }else{
                if(tempArray.size() > 0){
                    arrayOfIntList.add(k, tempArray);
                    k++;
                    tempArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    j=0;
                }
            }

            if(i == myarray.length-1 && tempArray.size()>0){
                arrayOfIntList.add(k, tempArray);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its really helpful too..:)